# Label and draw arrows next to the vertices of a cube in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-arrows

I have the following cube:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to draw arrows and label the cube like that:

[image]

(it says `a_1 \cdots a_n, b_1 \cdots b_n, c_1 \cdots c_n`).
How can I do that in LaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw three lines parallel to three edges with about `.5em` separation and add a label to each of them with the appropriate location and slope. See the last three lines in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7,> = latex]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[|<->|,yshift=-.5em] (-\cubex,-\cubey,0)--node[below]{$a_1 \cdots a_n$}++(\cubex,0,0);
\draw[|<->|,xshift=-.5em] (-\cubex,-\cubey,0)--node[above,sloped]{$c_1 \cdots c_n$}++(0,\cubey,0);
\draw[|<->|,shift={(.5em,-.5em)}] (0,-\cubey,0)--node[below,sloped]{$b_1 \cdots b_n$}++(0,0,-\cubez);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

A 2-D version would also be easier to implement like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7, >=latex]
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0)--(2,0)--(2,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (2,0)--++(45:.6)--++(0,1)--(2,1)--cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (2,1)--++(45:.6)--++(-2,0)--(0,1)--cycle;
\draw[|<->|,yshift=-.5em] (0,0)--node[below]{$a_1 \cdots a_n$}(2,0);
\draw[|<->|,xshift=-.5em] (0,0)--node[above,sloped]{$c_1 \cdots c_n$}(0,1);
\draw[|<->|,shift={(.5em,-.5em)}] (2,0)--node[below,sloped]{$b_1 \cdots b_n$}++(45:.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with a similar result:

> [image]

Comment: +1 To me it looks like the `b_1\dots b_n` line is not parallel to the cube, which would make sense since you've used a 2D `shift={(.5em,-.5em)}`.  I think that `\draw[|<->|] (0.1,-0.1-\cubey,0)--node[below,sloped]{$b_1 \cdots b_n$}++(0,0,-\cubez);` is slightly better.